# Visual Studio 2012 Live Preview Auto Reload

Tags: visual-studio-2012

It looks like VS2012 offers some what of a live preview mode when coding HTML/CSS via Page Inspector.

However it doesn't really help me much because I just see a prompt like the following which means every time I save I have to click that message.

How can I get VS2012 to truly auto reload the browser when I save a file in my solution? Also, it would be great if I could just use regular chrome instead of page inspector.

[image]